# Как html5 games связаны с html5?

Tags: html5, разработка-игр, phaser-framework

Информации по html5 games очень мало,посмотрел несколько статей на хабре и не совсем понял как это должно работать с html 5.Может как-то связано с API и движком Phaser. Но ведь все пишется на js, каким боком там вообще использовать html5 и именовать в честь этого игры?
Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

HTML-элемент `canvas`, на основе которого работает отображение в таких играх, не является частью JS. В html 4 этого элемента не было.

Раньше игры делались на flash. Поэтому название html 5 противопоставляется flash в данном случае, чтобы сразу было понятно на какой технологии сделана игра.

Если бы назвали `игра на JS`, то это могла бы быть игра на `div`-ах или на каком-то другом способе отображения, например на ascii-графике.